# Codeigniter Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysqli_result::fetch_assoc()

Tags: codeigniter

hello i want to update the row by clicking on edit button, but it giving me this error, kindly help

```
function updateUser()
{
    $data = stripslashes(file_get_contents("php://input"));
    $mydata = json_decode($data, true);
    $id = $mydata['sid'];
    //retrieve specific info 
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM admin WHERE id = {$id}";
    $result = $this->db->query($sql); 
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    echo json_encode($row); //returning json formate
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `$result->row_array();` instead of `$result->fetch_assoc();`

To prevent sql injection, you may also want to bind the `$id` separately instead of concatenating it into the query, like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM admin WHERE id = ?";
$result = $this->db->query($sql, array($id));
$row = $result->row_array();
```

See also: https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/queries.html#query-bindings